# Unique Object_id from timestamp with Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am creating a collection in MongoDB using pymongo. The elements of the collection already have a creation_date and I would like to use that to create the _id field. Since there is the possibility that more elements share the same creation_date, how can I create unique Object_id from that field?

bson has a function:
`bson.ObjectId.from_datetime(timestamp)` which warns about the non uniqueness of the generated id. Is there a way to add some randomness to it such that different object_ids are generated from the same date?

Comment: Why do you want the creation_date to be associated with the _id? As you said, since creation_date is not unique, you'll need some randomness anyway. So why not just use a completely random objectId?

Comment: because in my experience object_id are very fast and easy to use to make queries based on time

Comment: Wouldn't an index be a better fit for that?

Comment: I am not sure I follow, how that would keep the time info? Moreover, I was asking because adding randomness to the objectId built from a timestamp is an option in other languages implementations but not in Python, so it should be easily doable, but I don't know how

Comment: The right way to do what you're trying is to keep the _id random (just the normal objectID), and have an index on the created date to query with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bson objectId return a 24 hex digits variable which the first 8 digits is depends on the time and the remaining digits are some random number. If you create an id by using bson.ObjectId.from_datetime(args) function, it returns a 24 hex digits variable which last 16 digits are zero. By adding a random number to last part you can make it unique.
for generating random number you can use bson.objectId itself (last 16 digits)

ps: bason.objectId() returns a class instance and you should convert it into string.

```
import import time
from datetime import datetime
import bson

def uniqueTimeIdCreator(_time = time.time()):

    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(_time)
    timeId = str(bson.ObjectId.from_datetime(date))
    uniqueId = str(bson.ObjectId())

    return timeId[0:8] + uniqueId[8:]

def calc_time(_id):
    _time = bson.ObjectId(_id).generation_time
    return _time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")


specTime = time.time()

id1 = str(uniqueTimeIdCreator(specTime))
id2 = str(uniqueTimeIdCreator(specTime))

print(id1)
print(id2)

t1 = calc_time(id1)
t2 = calc_time(id2)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```